C言語で可変長引数を実装するときの番兵に関するベストプラクティス
概要
C言語で可変長引数の関数を実装したいです。下のコードを見てもらえればわかる通り番兵NULLを用いてループを管理するように実装しています。ただ、この方法ではgccでコンパイルするとwarning: comparison between pointer and integerが出ます。
始めに個数を明示するというのも考えられますが、あんまり気が進みません。
番兵を設けて実装するにあたって警告が出ないようにする方法はありますか？
コード
void validatePositive(int num, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num);

    while (num != NULL)
    {
        if (num < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Specify a non-negative integer: %d", num);
            exit(0);
        }
        num = va_arg(ap, int);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

環境

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on WSL2
gcc version 13.2.0 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4)


検索するとこんな記事があるので参考になるかも。最初の引数が文字配列の例 C言語　可変長引数関数について 【初心者向け】, C言語の可変長引数の関数の作り方, 可変個引数 | Programming Place Plus　Ｃ言語編　第５２章 そして最初の引数が整数の例 C言語の可変引数リスト「. . .」の使い方, 【C言語入門】関数の引数を可変にする方法（可変引数の使い方）, C言語で可変引数を受け取る

質問の事例は NULL と比較しようとするのが誤りですが、それは脇に置くとして可能なら可変長引数の関数は使わないに越したことはないです。 C の可変長引数は関数の静的な型情報が無いという状況を作ることによって実現されており、関数を受け取る側と渡す側で型が合わなくてもコンパイラが検出できないことがあるなど問題点があります。
渡す引数の型が全て同じなのであれば配列にして渡せばよろしいでしょう。 更にそれを可変長引数マクロで覆えば見かけ上は可変長引数であるかのように使えます。
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define validate_positive(...) validate_positive_function(sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int), (int[]){__VA_ARGS__})

void validate_positive_function(size_t count, int *num) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (num[i] < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Specify a non-negative integer: %d", num[i]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // 使用例。 外観上は可変長引数っぽく使える。
    validate_positive(1, -2, 4, 7, 5);
}


int型の変数なのにNULLと比較するからその警告が出ます
0 と比較しましょう


始めに個数を明示するというのも考えられますが、あんまり気が進みません。

最初に個数を指定するか、
validatePositive(3, 1, 2, 3);

最後に番兵として範囲外のint値を渡すしかないです。受け取り側はintで読むしかないので、この目的でNULLは使えません。
validatePositive(1, 2, 3, -1);

